# Python tkinter toplevel opens with a blank window, then after some time, opens all the widgets and formats correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, toplevel

I am creating a toplevel:

```
#Loading screen

main = Tk()

loading = Toplevel()

loading.title("Co-worker")
loading.iconbitmap(getcwd()+"/icons/appIcons/windowIcon.ico")
loading.config(bg="#758ECD")

mywidth = 275

imageLoc = f"{getcwd()}/icons/appIcons/appLogo.png"

img = Image.open(imageLoc)
wpercent = (mywidth/float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((mywidth,hsize), Image.LANCZOS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

imageLabel = Label(loading, image = image, style = "mainTitle.TLabel")
imageLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)

loadingBar = Progressbar(loading, orient = 'horizontal', mode = 'indeterminate', length = 250, style = "loading.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
loadingBar.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
loadingBar.start(10)

main.mainloop()
```

Then at the end of the code, I destroy the toplevel, once the main window has finished loading. (`loading.destroy()`)

When the code runs, for a short amount of time, the toplevel opens like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu4xp.png), before loading with all of it's widgets correctly.

How can I fix this so that it doesn't flash white first?

For all that are saying this, I just didn't include my imports as the list is very long. I am importing all the widgets directly from tkinter.ttk.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: In particular, where is the `mainloop()` call?

Comment: Try using `loading.withdraw()` to hide the `Toplevel` window then `loading.deiconify()` when object creation is complete.

Comment: @Barmar My code is way too long to upload including mainloop etc. I can edit it to be a simplified version if you'd like?

Comment: Yes, that's what we'd like -- that's what "minimal" means.

Comment: Remember that Tk is event based. To draw a window, you have to process some events (in mainloop). If your program is too busy doing other things first, it will take a while before the events get processed. The way around that is to use `after` to schedule the work on yet another event so you can get the widget drawing events handled and then do the work.

Comment: @hfaulkner saying that.....Sorry, I should've been more clear. I already have a main window and am importing Label and ProgressBar from ttk.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display `Progressbar` with no or very little flicker, I'm using `loading.withdraw()` to hide `Toplevel` window while it's being created.

I've used `after` to complete `Toplevel` display and to start `Progressbar`.
`After` is also used to create a time lag to simulate loading data, building GUI, etc.

I've also set 'loading' window as `transient` to guarantee it will display above 'main` window.

This works on Windows 10, Python 3.9.1

```py
import os
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#Loading screen
icon = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "icons", "appIcons", "windowIcon.ico")
imageLoc = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "icons", "appIcons", "appLogo.png")

main = tk.Tk()
main.deiconify()

loading = tk.Toplevel()
loading.withdraw()
loading.transient(main)

loading.title("Co-worker")
loading.iconbitmap(icon)
loading.config(bg="#758ECD")

mywidth = 275

img = Image.open(imageLoc)
wpercent = (mywidth/float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((mywidth,hsize), Image.LANCZOS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

imageLabel = tk.Label(loading, image = image, style = "mainTitle.TLabel")
imageLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)

loadingBar = ttk.Progressbar(
    loading, orient = 'horizontal', mode = 'indeterminate', length = 250,
    style = "loading.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
loadingBar.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

def closer():
    loadingBar.stop()
    loading.destroy()

def complete():
    loading.deiconify()
    loading.wait_visibility()
    loadingBar.start(10)
    
# complete Toplevel
main.after(100, complete)
# replace GUI completion with 5 second delay
main.after(5100, closer)

main.mainloop()
```